Imprimir sin tomar captura a la pantalla actual
a ver Para imprimir en JavaScript, se puede usar la función window.print() en el navegador para imprimir el contenido de la ventana actual ok lo entiendo pero suponiendo que quiero imprimir una interfaz de una página web, intentare ser claro tengo la página que quiero imprimir, pero no quiero mostrar dicha página en pantalla quiero que al dar click en un botón se abra la ventana de imprimir del navegador pero que no se muestre el diseño de la página en el programa. (En la ventana de imprimir si pero en el programa  no se si me explico también no se si exista alguna forma pues las que visto para imprimir toma captura a la pantalla actual y es justo eso lo que no quiero)

¿Quieres imprimir un contenido distinto al que se muestra en pantalla?

Exacto es lo que quiero hacer aunque soy novato no se si se pueda hacer?

¿Qué pasó de tu pregunta anterior?

la elimine creo que no me supe expresar bien pido perdon soy nuevo en esto y solo trato de aprender
